# TouchXML parse response with unquoted keys

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, touchjson

Is there a way to use TouchXML to parse json in which the key are not quoted, like this:

```
{ foo:"bar" }
```

I'm trying to parse the response from a webservice (google), so simply fixing the JSON code to be valid is not an option.

If it's not possible, is there a way to efficiently quote the keys as a preprocessing step?

Comment: While you can't fix it yourself, maybe you could at least file a bug report -- what service produces is not JSON, pure and simple, so if it is advertised as doing that, it is broken. I realize this won't solve your problem on short term but could help others over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to pre-parse it with RegexKitLite, using

```
uint numReplace = [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfRegex:@"(?<=[\\{,])[^:\\[\\{\"]+(?=:)" withString:@"\"$0\""];
```